# Overflow error on VB6 program running on Win XP

Tags: vb6

I'm getting a error message in a VB6 .exe file running on Windows XP.

I compile and "make it" on Windows 7/8, but always get an Overflow error message when it executes this two lines on XP:

```
sUrl = "C:\Arquivos de Programas\Internet Explorer\IEXPLORE.EXE http://example.com/WebForms/send.aspx?id=" & intCodID & "&type=500&usr=" & intCodUser 
openWeb = Shell(sUrl, vbMaximizedFocus)
```

`sUrl` is a `String` and `OpenWeb` is actually a `Integer`, but I already declared it as `Double` and as nothing (just `Dim OpenWeb`) and still get the overflow error.

---

**UPDATE**

Didn't managed to find out what was happening there, but another solution for calling IE:

```
Dim IE
sUrl = "http://www.google.com/"
Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
IE.Visible = True
IE.Navigate sUrl
```

Comment: Additionally, `intCodID` and `intCodUser` has both `Integer` values.

Comment: Not sure if it's related, but I'm pretty sure if you are passing that string into the command prompt/shell you need to supply double quotes around the path as it has spaces in it. As for the error, what are the actual values of `intCodID` and `intCodUser`? Does the program throw the overflow error on the `sUrl =` line or the `openWeb = Shell(sUrl, vbMaximizedFocus)` line?

Comment: @RianBattle You don't need double quotes for `Shell`. But you do for `WshShell.Run`.

Comment: @RianBattle, intCodID max value is "1.155.712" and intCodUser has four digits. Overflow is thrown in `openWeb = Shell(sUrl, vbMaximizedFocus)` line. Addedd extra quotes here.

Comment: Have you tried putting a breakpoint on `openWeb = Shell(sUrl, vbMaximizedFocus)`, but, instead of letting that execute, go into the Immediate window of the IDE, and submit: `?Shell(sUrl, vbMaximizedFocus)`? Just to see what happens then?

Comment: @JonasLima: Hit the [edit] link above to add your additional details to your question. It will help others so the pertinent info is in the question--a lot of people won't go slogging through comments for additional info.

Comment: Have you tried executing the line `?Shell(sUrl, vbMaximizedFocus)` in the debug window? You made a point of this gives an error when run on XP. Does it work when run on other OSs?

Comment: Why is there a VB.Net tag and a VB6 tag?  Surely this question is about one or the other?

Answer (score 0):

While the VB6 documentation says `Shell()` returns a Variant Double... that appears to be obsolete information left over from manuals for earler versions of VB.  Instead if you check the typelib info (i.e. look in the IDE's Object Browser) it actually returns a `Double` type result value.

As far as I can tell `Shell()` is a wrapper around a call to the `WinExec()` function.

The returned values are:

- `0` The system is out of memory or resources.
- `ERROR_BAD_FORMAT = 11` The .exe file is invalid.
- `ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND = 2` The specified file was not found.
- `ERROR_PATH_NOT_FOUND = 3` The specified path was not found.
- or a Process ID

Also contrary to the documentation, `Shell()` turns those error values into exceptions ("File not found", "Invalid procedure call or argument," etc.).  So if the call succeeds you always get back a PID value.

In all cases this is a DWORD.  So it always fits in a Double without the possibility of an overflow.  If you are seeing an overflow there is something else going wrong in your code.

Sadly a Double isn't particularly useful here, though it can at least hold the entire range of values.  But you'd normally want to carefully convert it to a Long value:

```
Option Explicit

Function DDoubleToDLong(ByVal DDouble As Double) As Long
    'Some functions like the intrinsic Shell() return a Double
    'to get around the lack of a UI4 type (DWORD, i.e. unsigned
    'Long) in VB.  Of course this isn't clean to pass to API
    'calls, making it sort of worthless so we need to do a type
    'conversion such as this:
    If DDouble > 2147483647# Then
        DDoubleToDLong = CLng(DDouble - 2147483648#) Or &H80000000
    Else
        DDoubleToDLong = CLng(DDouble)
    End If
End Function

Private Sub Form_Load()
    Dim DD As Double
    Dim DL As Long

    AutoRedraw = True
    Font.Name = "Courier New" 'Or other handy monospaced font.
    Font.Size = 12@

    DD = 0#: DL = DDoubleToDLong(DD): Print DD, DL, Hex$(DL)
    DD = 1#: DL = DDoubleToDLong(DD): Print DD, DL, Hex$(DL)
    DD = 2147483647#: DL = DDoubleToDLong(DD): Print DD, DL, Hex$(DL)
    DD = 2147483648#: DL = DDoubleToDLong(DD): Print DD, DL, Hex$(DL)
    DD = 4294967295#: DL = DDoubleToDLong(DD): Print DD, DL, Hex$(DL)
End Sub
```

`Integer` is worthless since overflows will be common.  `Long` without the conversion could cause overflows now and then.  `String` is just silly.

You also need to quote the values for the EXE and its arguments property, as in:

```
Option Explicit

Function DDoubleToDLong(ByVal DDouble As Double) As Long
    If DDouble > 2147483647# Then
        DDoubleToDLong = CLng(DDouble - 2147483648#) Or &H80000000
    Else
        DDoubleToDLong = CLng(DDouble)
    End If
End Function

Private Sub Form_Load()
    Dim sUrl As String
    Dim PID As Long

    sUrl = """C:\Arquivos de Programas\Internet Explorer\IEXPLORE.EXE"" " _
         & """http://example.com/WebForms/send.aspx?id=" _
         & intCodID _
         & "&type=500&usr=" _
         & intCodUser _
         & """"
    PID = DDoubleToDLong(Shell(sUrl, vbMaximizedFocus))
End Sub
```

Even this isn't *quite* "right" since exception handling should be added.  And both `intCodID` and `intCodUser` may require "cleansing" (UrlEncoding) depending on what types they are and what values they really have.  These might be `Integers` based on the names, with you relying on implicit String coercion?  If so they might be Ok.

BTW, as we see above special folder names get localized.  For that matter the system drive might not even be `C:\` at all!  So such paths should never be hard-coded but instead be built up based on values returned from calls to `Shell32` to look up the special folder.

Answer (score -1):

An integer can only be a whole number. No decimals.

You say it's declared as an integer therefore you cannot assign 1. anything, and you certainly can't assign anything like that to a number variable as it's not a valid number anyway as it has two decimal points.

You need to declare it as string.

Comment: Read properly before commenting. He has two errors.